# Why would an http server need to know the encoding of a filename?

Tags: html, http, nginx, firefox, browser

In short the scenario is simple, the contents of an HTML file are mostly ASCII encoded, except for an image filename which contains an UTF-8 character. This image name is never displayed. ASCII is the default encoding so we don't declare it anywhere. The question is, why then does the image fail to load? Assuming the octets in the filename of the image and in the HTML code are the same, why is the image not loaded properly?
Furthermore the problem appers to be fixed by explicitly telling the browser to use a UTF-8 encoding. Why did declaring the encoding affect the http server's ability to fetch a file?

You can find the specific technical details and sample code below:

Consider the simple html file "index.html":

```
<img src="cinturón.jpg"> </img>
```

and the following files in the directory:

```
~/root
|- index.html
|- cinturón.jpg
```

If I run "firefox index.html" or enter ~/root/index.html in a search bar, the image loads correctly.

However if I push the files to an nginx server that just forwards requests to the filesystem with [a classical setup](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/), the image fails until we declare the encoding in the html file through some charset attribute of the meta tag in the head element.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head
```

This directive tells the browser what the encoding of the (rest of the) file is, but the browser already interprets this file as ASCII by convention, this is how it understands the ascii  tag. Furthermore the filename is not displayable, so the browser doesn't really need to know what its encoding is, is it anything more than a sequence of bytes?

Filesystems for example, are not encoding aware, they just store filenames as they were given during writing, potentially hash them, and later compare the filename as given during reading. The only requirement is that the input interfaces at reading and writing use the same encoding, producing the same sequence of octets.
In my case the server and local OS and filesystem are the same, and the files are copied through git, which goes as far as checksumming their contents for verifying that they are the same, so we can be certain that the filenames in the filesystem are identical across environments.

I still can't figure out why images only load when clarifying the encoding of the browser, there's two possibilities.

A) the encoding directive causes the browser to change its behaviour.
B) the encoding directive causes the server to change its behaviour.

A would happen when the browser sends the request of the image to the server.
B would happen when the server sends the html file to the server. This would require that nginx interpret the HTML code in some way. I don't think of HTTP servers as reading or understanding HTML, so this is unlikely.

By inspecting the requests sent by the browser, I can see that the browser sends "/cintur%C3%B3n.jpg" when UTF-8 is declared and "/cintur%C3%83%C2%B3n.jpg" otherwise. The % are escape characters. C3, 83 C2 and B3 are hexadecimals for different octets. The browser sends ó as 2 octets when encoding is declared, but 4 octets when encoding is not. At this point the abnormality is present more clearly, declaring an encoding should not change the message, just how it is interpreted.

C3 B3 are the 2 octets that represent the ó character in utf-8, this is the basic multilingual plane, the second block, right after ascii (also known as basic latin in utf-8 specification). I still haven't figured out what C3 83 C2 B3 is

When inspecting the index.html file at rest with od (od -c index.html) we find that

"   c   i   n   t   u   r 303 263   n   .   j   p   g   "

Where 303 and 263 are the octets interpreted as unsigned octal numbers. A manual octal to hexadecimal conversion or running od with the -tx1 option confirm that these are B2 and C3 octets. So the ó character in the html file, when resting in the filesystem, both in the server and in my local machine, is 2 bytes long. Again, we know that there are 4 bytes between the r and n character in the request sent from the browser when the utf-8 encoding is noy declared.

Since off the top of my head I have no tools to verify how many bytes long the ó character is in my browser, I'll just assume that it is 4 bytes long, the next question to answer is whether the server sends a 2 byte ó or a 4 byte ó. Couldn't find out because the server logs are gzipped and mixed with other packet captures.

I might post additional debug info in the future, I'll probably use a dumber http server like busybox or C TCP sockets at this point.

Comment: Maybe I can rewrite the Q&A as "How to include non ascii characters in URLs"

Answer (score 2):

Filenames are communicated through URIs, URIs are composed of ASCII characters, not octets. Http servers and browsers demand that the encoding  be ASCII which is incompatible with a lot of other characters in encodings. In order to use any other encoding you would need to encode it using ascii characters and a specific escaping mechanism.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-35) defines the http syntax, filenames are transferred as URIs in a request message. URIs are in turn defined in [RFC 1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630) . Like most of the HTTP syntax, URIs only allow 7 bit ASCII characters, defined as [RFC 20](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20).

ASCII defines 128 characters with 7 bits, the remaining bit is wasted:

> For concreteness, we suggest the use of standard 7-bit ASCII embedded in an 8 bit byte whose high order bit is always 0

This means that a message containing an ó character would be considered illegal, or an indication that the stream is not padded with an eigth bit.
Therefore arbitrary octets cannot be transmitted as a URI.

Further limitations are imposed by the URI definition which make multibyte encodings particularly unsafe to use. Most importantly, spaces (hex 20) are considered the start and end of a URI when transmitted as an HTTP request, so if a character is encoded as more than one octet, and one of those is the same as an ASCII encoded space, then there will be trouble fetching that resource.

To protect against these classes of troubles, web browsers escape the protected characters and non ascii characters. As the URI standard defines:

> There is a conflict between the need to be able to represent many
> characters including spaces within a URI directly, and the need to
> be able to use a URI in environments which have limited character
> sets or in which certain characters are prone to corruption.  This
> conflict has been resolved by use of an hexadecimal escaping
> method which may be applied to any characters forbidden in a given
> context.

> The percent sign ("%", ASCII 25 hex) is used as the escape
> character in the encoding scheme and is never allowed for anything
> else.

Unsafe characters

> In canonical form, certain characters such as spaces, control
> characters, some characters whose ASCII code is used differently in
> different national character variant 7 bit sets, and all 8bit
> characters beyond DEL (7F hex) of the ISO Latin-1 set, shall not be
> used unencoded.

Characters beyond DEL (7F hex) cannot be sent as octets without a representation, URIs are supposed to be represented in written form, pen and paper if necessary.

> It is possible to express any URI using
> 7-bit ASCII characters so that URIs may,
> if necessary, be passed using pen and ink.

The simplicity of a 7 bit base set was used for this purpose, URIs are meant for human understanding, not just machines, so they cannot be considered as octets, they are ASCII characters.

In short, URIs should be composed of ASCII characters, if another character set is to be used, they should be escaped with a % (Hex 25) followed by the ASCII encoded hex values of the octets desired. The http server would then need to look for % and read the following two octets as appropriate, and transform that to a single octet. This is so impractical and complex that the most sensible solution is to desist in the usage of non ASCII characters in URIs.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Nginx server's charset set to in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf? If it is set to a charset that doesn't understand the 'ó' character (most likely ASCII) then it will try to load your image as cintur303263n.jpg, which of course doesn't exist on your file system so it displays a broken image. If either the server or browser is explicitly informed of the expected charset then it will use the appropriate encoding and display your image properly.

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks for taking a look into this. I couldn't find any charset encoding declared in nginx's configuration. What specifically would we be looking for here? The encoding of the files it is serving? Does nginx need to know that? Does the mailman need to know the language of the mail they deliver?

Comment: I revised the question details, let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: @TomasZubiri You would look for the 'charset' directive in the conf file. Actually, I have lived in countries where if a diacritical mark is missing then the letter will go to the wrong place. :D I digress though. Browsers can and my opinion should be set to auto-detect the encoding type. The fact is quite often they are not, so it is up to the page to tell the browser the encType which is why you experienced what you did. In the case of a user and developer that isn't aware of this. Then your last line of defense is for the webserver to specify a default encType.